# Check if date is some day of the year

Tags: php, date

We use some line to display if we are open or not. For this we use this line:

```
<?php $weekday = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('w'); ?>
<?php $hour    = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('G'); ?>
<?php if ($weekday >= 1 && $weekday <= 5 && $hour >= 8.30 && $hour < 17.30) : ?>
<p>Open</p>

<?php else : ?>
<p>Closed</p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

But I want to expand this line, that we are closed because of a national day of the year. 
 How can I expand this code with some specific dates. For example 14/05/2015 and 24/05/2015 and 25/05/2015.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Try something like this:

```
$weekday = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('w');
$hour    = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('G');
$closedDates = array('2015-05-14', '2015-05-24', '2015-05-25');
$date = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
if ($weekday >= 1 && $weekday <= 5 && $hour >= 8.30 && $hour < 17.30 && !in_array($date, $closedDates)) {
 ...your magic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marius! But how do I include the line with the times of opening and day of the week from 1 to 5?

Comment: @Jelle. See my update

Comment: Works wonderful! :)

Comment: @Marius Do you know how to do this in magento 2?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Magento `Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d')` method to get the current date and verify that against a string with the date

```
<?php 
$weekday = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('w');
$hour    = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('G');
$date    = Mage::getSingleton('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');
if ($weekday >= 1 && $weekday <= 5 || $date == '2015-05-20') : ?>
```

*Sidenote*
This does not take into account the timezone of the user, it's based on the servers timezone so for an international shop (with clients in multiple timezones) you're better off using Javascript

[EDIT] Thanks to Marius for correcting the method used for retrieving the date

Comment: Thanks Sander! I updated my request, because I do not know how to implement this in our situation.